# Python: how to iterate only over values in dictionary and append to values?

Tags: python

I have the following code and I am trying to iterate across values during a search and then append to the values.

```
for delvt, pin in zip(temp_delvt_list, temp_pin_list):
    temp[delvt].append(pin)
    print temp
SPFFile = open(pathSPFfiles + temp_cell + ".spf", "r")
for line in SPFFile:
    for pin in temp[delvt]:
         print pin
```

Output of temp is:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'0.1995': ['in1', 'in2'], '0.399': ['in0', 'y']})
```

Output of pin is only:

```
in0
iny
```

Why is pin not outputting in1 and in2 also?

Comment: I replaced "for pin in temp" with "for tp in temp" and got the same answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're outside of the loop that changes `delvt`, hence you only use the last assigned value.

Comment: I formatted my code incorrectly in the question and I have updated the question with the correct formatting.

Comment: `delvt` still does not change; and on the other hand, you iterate over the lines of the file, but never access the line content. Are you sure, `delvt` wasn’t supposed to be `line`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict_var.values()` to iterate values of `dict_var`